# How to replace dual boot HDD with SSD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, upgrade, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 5567 that came with mechanical HDD of 1 TB that has Dual boot (W10 and MX Linux) for which I want to change to a SSD (they told me that is faster, I don't know in which percentage) and I have several doubts.

1. Could be the new SSD bigger? (i.e. 2TB)
2. Is there a way to clone exactly the new in order to only replace it and after boot all looks the same and dual boot works exactly as now?
3. Or new SSD should be installed formatted and then make a windows installation and after that begin to copy data from old to new disk?

Thanks I'm advance

Comment: If you need to ask then don't do it, it's as simple as that. Do the smart thing instead: Backup personal files, reinstall both OSes the same way you did before, end of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new SSD will be MUCH faster. Depending on your metric, 5 - 1000 times.

The new SSD can be bigger, but it can be a bit tricky to resize the drive to take advantage of this. Exactly how tricky depends on the drive layout.

You can clone the drive exactly and just replace it - you need to make sure you use a SATA SSD (which is older and slower tech but a very worthwhile upgrade - and very common).  You would do a bitcopy of the drive and swap it.  I dont know the appropriate Windows tools (ddrescue works under Linux, as does dd).  Macrium Reflect is a name often bandied around in the Windows world to clone disks.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Do you know some guide or link that talk about how to replace with a bigger SSD? That explains thtelle tricky part you say.

Comment: It really depends on how the drive is partitioned and what the end-goal is, so I don't have a guide/link.  Have a look at "gparted" and do some Googling around that as its likely the easiest tool for whatever the job turns out to be.   You should consider any partition resize operations to be high risk and make sure you have a good backup before you attempt them.